# Overlapping edges in graphviz

Tags: graphviz, overlap, directed-graph, edges

I've two overlapping edges and don't know why:

```
digraph G {
    graph [rankdir=LR, overlap=false];
    subgraph cluster1 {
       d1;
       n1;
    }
    subgraph cluster2 {
       n2;
       d2;
    }
    n1 -> n2;
    n2 -> n1;
    d0 -> d1;
    d0 -> d2;
}
```

[image]

Is there any way to display both edges `n1 -> n2` and `n2 -> n1` separately? Removing the clusters is not an option but would help ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trial-and-error solution (don't ask me why this works...):

```
digraph G {
    graph [rankdir=LR, overlap=false];
    subgraph cluster1 {
       d1;
       n1;
    }
    subgraph cluster2 {
       n2;
       d2;
    }
    n1 -> n2;
    n1 -> n2[constraint=false, dir=back];
    n2 -> n1[style=invis];
    d0 -> d1;
    d0 -> d2;
}
```

[image: graphviz output]

Answer (score 4):

A solution making use of the [portPos](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k%3aportPos) modifier:

```
digraph G {
    graph [rankdir=LR, overlap=false];
    subgraph cluster1 {
       d1;
       n1;
    }
    subgraph cluster2 {
       n2;
       d2;
    }
    n1:sw -> n2:nw;
    n2:ne -> n1:se;
    d0 -> d1;
    d0 -> d2;
}
```

Another solution is to make use of the dir and [color](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d%3acolor) modifiers:

```
digraph G {
    graph [rankdir=LR, overlap=false];
    subgraph cluster1 {
       d1;
       n1;
    }
    subgraph cluster2 {
       n2;
       d2;
    }
    n2 -> n1[dir=both color="red:blue"];
    d0 -> d1;
    d0 -> d2;
}
```

You can even use `color="black:black"` if you want to maintain the black and white coloring scheme.

Comment: Thank you very much so far! I need these two edges, but second solution was interesting to know. First solution is limited. Please have a look at: digraph G {
    graph [rankdir=LR, overlap=false];
    subgraph cluster1 {
       d1;
       n1;
    }
    subgraph cluster3 {
       d3;
       n3;
    }
    subgraph cluster2 {
       n2;
       d2;
    }
    n1:se -> n2:ne [color=green];
    n2 -> n1  [color=red];
    d0 -> d1;
    d0 -> d2;
    d0 -> d3
}