# Graphiz: Parallel egdes in digraph

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to build a dependecy scheme of a program as a digraph in dot. Therefore I used the following code:

```
digraph LINK { 
    rankdir=LR; 
    ranksep=0.65;
    nodesep=0.40;
    splines=false; 
    overlap=false;
    concentrate=false; 
    node[shape=box]; 
    subgraph clusterAPP {
            label="Application"; 
            style=dashed; 
            nodeA[label="d = func(...);"]; 

    }; 
    subgraph clusterFB{
            color=red;
            label="Wrapper"; 
            style=dashed; 
            rank=same; 
            wrapper[label="wrapper"]; 
            real[label="pointer to\nreal func"]; 
            wrapper -> real [constraint=false,label="dlopen\ndlsym"]; 
    }
    subgraph clusterBACKEND {
            label="Backend"
            style=dashed; 
            func[label="float func(...)"]; 
    };
    nodeA -> wrapper; 
    real -> func[weight=10];  
    func->real[color=blue]; 
}
```

This results in [image]

The problems are now:

- The egdes between `real` and `func` overlap. How can I separate them that they are easy to recognize.
- Why has the edge from `wrapper` to `real` the wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question has already been given elsewhere [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845570/overlapping-edges-in-graphviz/#9863611), what it boils down to is you can either use [ports postions](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:portPos) or use the trick mentioned by the infamous [marapet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63733/marapet) to add an extra edge in the same direction, remove it's constraint and reverse the edge's direction and hide the edge pointing back.

Or to put it in code:

```
real -> func [weight=10]                    // Remains unaltered  
real -> func [constraint=false, dir=back]   // Remove the constraint and reverse the edge
func -> real [style=invis]                  // Hide the edge pointing pack
```

As to why the other edge is pointing in the wrong direction, this has to do with [a bug in relation to `constraint`](http://www.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=2055) and should be fixed in version `2.27`. You may be working with an older version. (I know I am, as a lot of *NIX package managers still have 2.26.X by default).

To fix this you will either need to manually update your Graphviz to a newer version or (if you already have a newer version or can't/don't want to update) add `dir=back` to that nodes attribute.

Putting everything together the result is this:

[image]

Using the following DOT code:

```
digraph LINK { 
    rankdir=LR; 
    ranksep=0.65;
    nodesep=0.40;
    splines=false; 
    overlap=false;
    concentrate=false; 
    node[shape=box]; 
    subgraph clusterAPP {
            label="Application"; 
            style=dashed; 
            nodeA[label="d = func(...);"]; 

    }; 
    subgraph clusterFB{
            color=red;
            label="Wrapper"; 
            style=dashed; 
            rank=same; 
            wrapper[label="wrapper"]; 
            real[label="pointer to\nreal func"]; 
    }
    subgraph clusterBACKEND {
            label="Backend"
            style=dashed; 
            func[label="float func(...)"]; 
    };

    nodeA -> wrapper; 
    wrapper -> real [constraint=false, dir=back, label="dlopen\ndlsym"];  // Added reverse direction
    real -> func [weight=10]                    // Remains unaltered  
    real -> func [constraint=false, dir=back]   // Remove the constraint and reverse the edge
    func -> real [style=invis]                  // Hide the edge pointing pack

}
```